# Mathematical proof using sequences

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, limsup-and-liminf, proof-explanation

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence.
a) Prove that there exists an $s$ such that for any $r > s$ there exists an $M ∈ \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n ≥ M$ we have
$x_n < r$.
b) If s is a number as in a), then prove $ \limsup_n x_n ≤ s$.
c) Show that if $S$ is the set of all s as in a), then $\lim \sup\{x_n\} = \inf S$.

For part a) I let s = $\sup \{ X_n\}$. Let M=1, then you can prove that $X_n$ is less than or equal to $\sup \{X_n \}$.

For part b) Again let $s = \sup\{X_n\}$ then I proved that $\limsup {X_n}$ less than or equal to $\sup \{Xn \}$.

Part c is really difficult and I am not sure where to start for that problem.

Comment: What is your definition of $\limsup$? I used c) as my usual definition of $\limsup$.

Comment: My definition of llimsup{Xn} = lim{An} where An = {sup{Xk: k>= n}. I don't know how that definition would help in part c.

Comment: First: show that $\limsup x_n \in S$. Second: show that for all $s \in S$, $\limsup x_n \le s$.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, one last question how would you go about proving that limsup{Xn} exists in S. I understand how to prove the other two

Comment: nevermind I got it thank you for your help